# Define Multiple Globals files per environment in Nightwatchjs

Tags: javascript, selenium, nightwatch.js

I am trying to define multiple globals files on an environment bases in NightwatchJS, but cannot seem to get it done correctly.

The documentation here http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#external-globals indicates this is a possibility, but I can only get a globals file picked up at the top level of the config file.  If I try to embed them inside the environment nodes, they are ignored.

`"chromeTR" : {
      "persist_globals": true,
      "globals": {
        "Report":true 
      },
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "test_card" : "4111111111111111",
        "test_alt_card" : "0000405060708090",
        "chromeOptions": {
          "args" : ["--no-sandbox"]
        },
        "cli_args" : {
          "webdriver.gecko.driver" : "drivers/chromedriver"
        }
      }
    },`

This needs to be in place because I am defining a custom `before` function depending on environment.

Also, because this is the `before` function, I am unable to use a globals variable defined in the environment to trigger a switch within the function itself, since the `before` function does not have insight to the browser object.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use

```
this.client.globals.Report
```

or

```
this.client.globals.test_settings.globals.Report
```

within the before function to access your environment-specific global variables - is that not working?